# Codekit (less/css) preserve some comments when minified

Tags: less, minify, codekit

Sorry if I'm bored with this question but there is a trick to preserve some comments when minified with Codekit (Less)?

Answer (score 2):

Multiline comments starting with an exclamation mark (like `/*! Comment … */`) are preserved by lesscss.

Answer (score 1):

Normal CSS style comments are preserved (like `/* Hello */`) while single line comments (`// Hello`) are cut out. CodeKit just uses the less executable so it's all the same as with less.

Reference: http://lesscss.org/#-comments

Comment: Thank you, yes I found that CodeKit has build-in options to preserve or not comments and headers.